# JSP Custom tags : Cannot convert [B@33818e of type class [B to class [Ljava.lang.Byte

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl, taglib

I am working in Spring Framework MVC application with a WebLogic server. I am using jstl 1.2. and I have a custom taglib created by me

I have this Tag created:

```
public class DisplayImageTag extends SimpleTagSupport {

    private Collection<Image> images;
    private byte[] logo;
    private String action;

    @Override
    public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {

        PageContext pc = (PageContext)getJspContext();
        JspWriter out = getJspContext().getOut();
        String fullPath = TDKUtils.getTDKPath(pc);

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(" ");
        if(action != null) {
            action = action.trim();
        }

        if (this.images!=null) {            
            for (Image img : this.images) {

                Long id = img.getId()!=null ? img.getId() : img.getTempId();

                sb.append("<img src='" + fullPath + "/displayImage?" + DisplayImageServlet.IMG_ID + "=" + id+"&resize=true' align='bottom' >&nbsp;");

                // create and show delete button if action arg passed
                if (action != null && !action.trim().equals("")) {
                    sb.append("<a href='" + this.action + "?name=image&id=" + img.getTempId() + "&action=delete'>");
                    sb.append("<img src='" + fullPath + "/images/delete.png' ");
                    sb.append("alt='Delete picture' class='whattodo' style='border-width: 0pt;' align='bottom' /></a>");
                }
            }
        }
        out.print(sb);
    }

    public void setImages(Collection<Image> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public void setLogo(byte[] logo) {
        this.logo = logo;
    }
}
```

and this bean

```
public class Club implements java.io.Serializable {


    private byte[] logo;
    ..
}
```

and in my JSP

```
<tdk:displayImage logo="${club.logo}"  />
```

But I got this error:

```
javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert [B@33818e of type class [B to class [Ljava.lang.Byte;
```

Comment: Can you try Byte[] ?

Comment: @KorayTugay please convert to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely class cast does not work with primitive types, Byte[] should work.